# Prove $\{A_1, \cdots ,A_n\}$ is a partition of $A$ given $\{S_1, \cdots, S_n\}$ is a partition of $\Omega$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A \subseteq \Omega$ and $\{S_1,\cdots ,S_n\}$ be a partition of $\Omega$. Let $A_i = A \cap S_i$. Prove $\{A_1, \cdots ,A_n\}$ is a partition of $A$.

I'm having trouble formalizing this with mathematical symbols but I think I get the idea behind the problem...

To prove something is a partition we must show that is satisfies the conditions:

- 1) The subsets are mutually disjoint
- 2) The union of the subsets is equal to the whole sample space

We are given that $\{S_1,\cdots ,S_n\}$ is a partition of the sample space $\Omega$ so we know the collection of $S_i$ are mutually disjoint and their union $=\Omega$

We can also view this intuitively by the following example. Let $\Omega$ be a piece of lined paper. Let the lines on this paper represent the partitions $S_i$ with $1\le i \le n$ where $n$ equals the number of lines. Then draw a circle on this piece of paper and no matter what circle you draw (no matter how imperfect the shape) the lines will always divide the circle into mutually disjoint partitions $A_i$ that all together add up to give the full circle.

There are two cases for each section separated by lines:

- Case 1 - No part of the circle is inside the section meaning $A_i\notin S_i$
- Case 2 - Some or all of the circle is inside the section meaning $A_i \in S_i$

How do I put all of this logic together in symbols to write it in a concise, mathematical way?

Thank you!

Comment: "$A_i \notin S_i$" and "$A_i \in S_i$" are incorrect. By incorrect I don't mean they're false, I mean they don't make sense. $A_i$ and $S_i$ are both subsets of $\Omega$, so comparing them with $\in$ is wrong. Probably the relation you're looking for is $A_i \cap S_j = \varnothing$, which can be read with English words as "the intersection of $A_i$ and $S_j$ is the empty set", or equivalently "no point is both in $A_i$ and in $S_j$" or in fewer words "$A_i$ and $S_j$ are disjoint".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly

> $$A_i\cap A_j= \{x\in \Omega | x\in A \land x\in S_i \land x\in S_j\}=A\cap S_i\cap S_j=\begin{cases} A_i & i=j \\ \varnothing & i\ne j\end{cases}.$$

So the sets are disjoint.

Now let $x\in A$. Then as $A\subseteq \Omega$, $\exists 1\le i\le n$ so that $x\in S_i$ because $\{S_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a partition of $\Omega$, in logical symbols

> $$\Omega = \bigcup_{i=1}^nS_i=\{x\in\Omega | \exists 1\le i\le n \text{ such that } x\in S_i\}.$$

Because $x\in A \land x\in S_i$, we have $x\in \{x\in \Omega | x\in A\land x\in S_i\}=A\cap S_i=A_i$. Hence $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a partition of $A$ by definition.

Comment: What does $\wedge$ mean? Sorry, it is the first time I have come across it. Since you used it in the listing of the properties of the set elements, can it just be read as "and"?

Comment: @DavidSouth apologies, you said "logical symbols" so I made a point to use them:  $\land$ means "and"

Comment: Well, I'm glad you used them because now I know what they mean :) thank you!

Comment: @DavidSouth You're welcome, and good luck with your studies.

Comment: I don't particularly recommend using the same name $x$ for two different variables, in $x\in \{x\in \Omega | x\in A\land x\in S_i\}$. Would probably be easier to understand as $x\in \{y\in \Omega | y\in A\land y\in S_i\}$.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having trouble formalizing this with mathematical symbols but I think I get the idea behind the problem...

Frame challenge: we don't need symbols for a formal mathematical proof.

**First**, we want to prove that the $A_i$ are disjoint. Consider two of them, $A_i$ and $A_j$. Being disjoint means "if a point is in one of them, then it's not in the other". So we're going to prove that. Let $x$ be a point in $A_i$.

We know that $A_i$ is the intersection of $A$ and $S_i$, which in particular means that $A_i$ is a subset of $S_i$. So, if $x$ is a point of $A_i$, then $x$ is also a point of $S_i$. But we know that $S_i$ and $S_j$ are disjoint, so that means that $x$ is not a point of $S_j$. And we also know that $A_j$ is a subset of $S_j$, so if $x$ is not a point of $S_j$, then $x$ is not a point of $A_j$.

Thus we have proven that for any point $x$ in $A_i$, $x$ cannot be a point in $A_j$. This proves that $A_i$ and $A_j$ are disjoint. This is true for any pair $A_i$ and $A_j$, so the whole family $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ is pairwise-disjoint.

**Second**, we want to prove that the union of the $A_i$ is all of $A$. In other words, we want to prove that for any point $x$ in $A$, there exists an $i$ such that $x$ is a point of $A_i$. So we're going to prove that. Let $x$ be a point of $A$.

$A$ is a subset of $\Omega$, so if $x$ is a point of $A$, then $x$ is also a point of $\Omega$. We know that the union of the $S_i$ is all of $\Omega$, so there exists an $i$ such that $x$ is a point of $S_i$. So, $x$ is a both in $S_i$ and in $A$: this is the definition of being in their intersection $S_i \cap A$. But we know that $A_i = S_i \cap A$. So we have proven that $x$ is in $A_i$.

Thus we have proven that for any point $x$ in $A$, there exists an $i$ such that $x$ is in $A_i$. This proves that the union of the $A_i$ covers $A$.

We have proven the two conditions: the family of subsets $(A_1, \ldots, A_n)$ is indeed a partition of $A$.

> We can also view this intuitively by the following example. Let $\Omega$ be a piece of lined paper.

Pardon the flashy colours. Here is a visual of partition $(S_1, S_2, \ldots, S_n)$ of $\Omega$, and the induced partition $(A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_n)$ of $A$:

[image: Partition S1,s2,...,Sn of Omega, and induced partition A1,A2,...,An of A]